# Inconsistency in disk usage value between df & du unix command output on mount-drive

Tags: linux, disk-usage

See inconsistency in disk usage value between `df` & `du` unix command output on mount-drive.

Here is sample result from `df -k` command output on a mount point.

```
df -k /mount/point | awk '{print $3}'
Used
245661696
```

If we calculate K block to bytes then its : 245661696 * 1024 = **251557576704**

Here is sample result from `du` command output on a mount point main directory (mount point itself)

```
du -b --max-depth=0 /mount/point
375628722011
```

`du` output : **375628722011** which is almost *124GB* extra when compared with `df` output!

Am I missing something. Some real time result from du will always be different?

Comment: @vinWin I-'m not sure this is related but look at my question since 2014 here:https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140473/why-does-df-h-show-out-of-sync-space-used

Comment: This has been discussed to death here.

Comment: thanks for pointers. I tried with `-x` option of `du` to see if it yields _correct_ result, but I am afraid its not. I also looked at `stat --file-system $HOME`  yielding to 4096 , but wasn't clear how it computes up for my conversion. All I need is correct output bytes from `du` so that I can convert to GB/TB. Any help to solve this mystry much appreciated..